# Java snow animation

Tags: java, animation, physics, processing

I was inspired by [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74651/javascript-snow-animation) to write a graphic snow animation in Java/Processing. It works great, but it has some design issues.

The full project is [here](https://github.com/JJ-Atkinson/SnowDay) on github;

## `Main`

```
package com.jatkin.snowday;

import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PGraphics;

/**
 * Created by Jarrett on 02/04/16.
 */
public class Main extends PApplet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {PApplet.main(Main.class.getCanonicalName());}

    final int backgroundColor = color(0, 146, 178);
    final World world = new World();

    /**
     * Processing 3 has changed the basic format for starting an app from raw
     * java. Size now must be called from `settings`.
     */
    @Override
    public void settings() {
        size(500, 300, FX2D);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        fill(255);
        noStroke();

        background(backgroundColor);
        world.tick(sketchWidth(), sketchHeight());
        world.render(getGraphics());
    }
}
```

---

## `World`

```
package com.jatkin.snowday;

import com.jatkin.snowday.snowflake.FlakeFactory;
import com.jatkin.snowday.snowflake.Snowflake;
import processing.core.PGraphics;
import processing.core.PVector;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This class controls all physics for SnowDay.
 *
 * Created by Jarrett on 02/04/16.
 */
public class World {
    private float gravity;
    private List<Snowflake> flurry;
    private Wind wind;
    private int flakeCountTarget;


    public World() { this(2); } // FIXME magic number

    public World(int gravity) {
        this.gravity = gravity;
        flurry = new ArrayList<>();
        wind = new Wind();
        flakeCountTarget = 200;// FIXME magic number
    }

    /**
     * Advance the snow animation 1 frame
     */
    public void tick(int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
        wind.tick();
        manageSnowflakeCount(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        edgeWrapSnowflakes(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        updateSnowflakePosition();
    }

    /**
     * Wrap flakes around edged of the screen.
     */
    private void edgeWrapSnowflakes(int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
        flurry.forEach(snowflake -> {
            if (snowflake.getPosition().x > screenWidth)
                snowflake.getPosition().x = 0;
            else if (snowflake.getPosition().x < 0)
                snowflake.getPosition().x = screenWidth;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reset off screen flakes.
     * @param screenWidth
     * @param screenHeight
     */
    private void manageSnowflakeCount(int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
        flurry.removeIf(flake -> flake.getPosition().y > screenHeight);

        int newFlakeCount = (int)Math.sqrt(flakeCountTarget - flurry.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < newFlakeCount; i++)
            flurry.add(FlakeFactory.genRandomSnowflake(screenWidth));

    }

    /**
     * Apply wind, gravity and rotation to all the snowflakes
     */
    private void updateSnowflakePosition() {
        for (Snowflake flake : flurry) {
            PVector flakePosition = flake.getPosition();
            float weight = flake.getWeight();

            float downwardsMotion = weight*gravity;
            float windMotion = (wind.getSpeed() / weight);

            flake.getSpeed().set(windMotion, downwardsMotion);
            flakePosition.add(flake.getSpeed());

            flake.setRotation(flake.getRotation() + flake.getRotationSpeed());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Render all the snowflakes this world has onto the surface
     * @param surface
     */
    public void render(PGraphics surface) {
        for (Snowflake flake : flurry) {
            flake.render(surface);
        }
    }


    public float getGravity() {
        return gravity;
    }
}
```

---

## `Wind`

```
package com.jatkin.snowday;

import static java.lang.Math.*;

/**
 * Created by Jarrett on 02/05/16.
 */
public class Wind {
    private final static float maxWind = 6;
    private final static int maxDurationInMs = 5000;
    private final static int minDurationInMs = 2000;
    private float targetSpeed = 0;
    private float speed = 0;
    private long windStopTime = 0;

    public void tick() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (now > windStopTime)
            calculateNewWind();
        else
            interpolateWindSpeed();
    }

    private void calculateNewWind() {
        float newWindSpeed = (float)sqrt(random()*maxWind*maxWind);
        if (random()>0.5) newWindSpeed = -newWindSpeed;
        int newDuration = (int) (random() * (maxDurationInMs - minDurationInMs)) + minDurationInMs;

        targetSpeed = newWindSpeed;
        windStopTime = newDuration + System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private void interpolateWindSpeed() {
        float speedDiff = targetSpeed - speed;
        float speedChange = (float) (sqrt(abs(speedDiff))/15);

        if (speedDiff > 0)
            speed += speedChange;
        else
            speed -= speedChange;
    }

    public float getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }
}
```

---

## `snowflake.Snowflake`

```
package com.jatkin.snowday.snowflake;

import processing.core.PGraphics;
import processing.core.PVector;

/**
 * Created by Jarrett on 02/04/16.
 */
public abstract class Snowflake {

    private float weight = 1;
    private float rotation = 0;
    private float rotationSpeed = 0;
    final private PVector position = new PVector();
    final private PVector speed = new PVector();

    /**
     * Render this flake on the surface
     * @param surface
     */
    abstract public void render(PGraphics surface);


    public float getRotationSpeed() {
        return rotationSpeed;
    }

    public void setRotationSpeed(float rotationSpeed) {
        this.rotationSpeed = rotationSpeed;
    }

    public PVector getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public float getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(float weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public PVector getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public float getRotation() {
        return rotation;
    }

    public void setRotation(float rotation) {
        this.rotation = rotation;
    }
}
```

---

## `snowflake.SquareSnowflake`

```
package com.jatkin.snowday.snowflake;

import processing.core.PConstants;
import processing.core.PGraphics;

/**
 * Created by Jarrett on 02/04/16.
 */
public class SquareSnowflake extends Snowflake {
    private final float size = 13;

    @Override
    public void render(PGraphics surface) {
        surface.pushMatrix();

        surface.translate(getPosition().x, getPosition().y - size/2);
        surface.rotate(getRotation());
        surface.rectMode(PConstants.CENTER);
        surface.rect(0, 0, size, size);

        surface.popMatrix();
    }

}
```

---

## `snowflake.FlakeFactory`

```
package com.jatkin.snowday.snowflake;

/**
 * Created by Jarrett on 02/05/16.
 */
public class FlakeFactory {

    public static Snowflake genRandomSnowflake(int maxXLoc) {
        Snowflake flake = new SquareSnowflake();
        flake.setWeight((float)(Math.random()/2)+1);      // FIXME: magic numbers
        flake.setRotationSpeed((float)(Math.random()*Math.PI/18d));
        flake.getPosition().x = (int)(Math.random()*maxXLoc);
        return flake;
    }

}
```

The questions I have are ordered in greatest to least importance to me.

My main issue with this code is the magic numbers. Magic numbers are everywhere. I was able to sensibly move some of the numbers to `private static final` fields, but some of the rest don't seem to belong anywhere. For example `FlakeFactory#genRandomSnowflake`:

```
public static Snowflake genRandomSnowflake(int maxXLoc) {
    Snowflake flake = new SquareSnowflake();
    flake.setWeight((float)(Math.random() / 2 ) + 1);
    flake.setRotationSpeed((float)(Math.random() * Math.PI / 18d));
    flake.getPosition().x = (int)(Math.random() * maxXLoc);
    return flake;
}
```

Many magic numbers exist here, mostly to keep the animation rate sane.

Other than that, how does my overall design look? I encapsulated nearly all the physics code in `World`. Is it a good or bad idea?

I think most of the code is reasonably split up into useful, descriptive methods with some documentation where I thought it was required. How clean is the overall code inside the methods? Documentation quality?

<sub>Keep in mind that I am completely self taught.</sub>

---

### Installing processing

Processing isn't on Maven central, so to install it you need to download it.

1. Go to https://processing.org/download/ and download version 3.0.1
2. Unpack the download and locate the \core\library folder
3. Add the entire folder to your classpath

Comment: You're making square snowflakes too?

Comment: I'm not very artsy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks really good! I just have a few improvements, nothing big.

`Wind.interplorateWindSpeed()`

A math function called `signum` could be used instead of `if` statements.

```
float speedDiff = targetSpeed - speed;

float speedChange = (float) (sqrt(abs(speedDiff))/15);

speed += speedChange * signum(speedDiff);
```

`Wind`

You might consider moving all the private `float`s values into a constructor, just for consistency.

**Thoughts**

Really these are just small tweaks, you have some very well-written and documented code!

The next thing to do would be to make more types of snowflakes (hexagons, stars, textures) for variety.

Comment: sqrt() takes care of abs()?

Comment: @200_success For sure not, unless you [want NaN](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt(double)).

Comment: I was using just `sqrt()`, but all the snowflakes disappeared when the wind changed.

Comment: @maaartinus sorry, my bad.